# VS 2017 RC asp.net core system.net.http confliction issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been working on a .net core web application for about 3 months now.  With the release of VS2017, I thought I'd pull it down this weekend to try out the auto migration it has as well as the new enviro.  When I did this, all went well with the exception of the System.Net.Http reference.

I'm receiving an error that states;

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1956,5): warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
1>Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Net.Http, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "1.5.0.0" [C:\Users\reamj\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.http\2.2.22\lib\portable-net40+sl4+win8+wp71+wpa81\System.Net.Http.dll] to Version "4.1.1.0" [C:\Users\reamj\.nuget\packages\system.net.http\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Net.Http.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
```

Being that this is within the dll, I'm really not sure how to resolve the issue.  It would be nice to resolve this to leverage VS17. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Below is my csproj (no longer project.json) configuration.

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>ProjectName</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>ProjectName</PackageId>
    <UserSecretsId>noooooooooooooooooooope</UserSecretsId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*;**\*.cshtml;appsettings.json;web.config">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid.NetCore" Version="1.0.0-rtm-00002" />
   
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="1.10.2" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader" Version="14.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="8.1.0" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core" Version="2016.3.1118" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="bower install" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Search issues at corefx GitHub repo related to this namespace and you should know what can be the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

(1) Removing `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.3" />`
(You shouldn't need this package to run WebApi on .net core.)

(2) Change the SendGrid to `<PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.0.12" />`

Comment: Thank you so much!